# docker on android (gnuroot debian)

Tags: android, linux, docker, debian

I am trying to install docker-ce on my android (6.0.1) over gnurooot debian, the installation fails with "no permission to read /proc/cmdline".
Can you help me to fix it?
here is the error i get

```
Sponsored by:

 _____                   _
|_   _| ___  ___  ___  _| | _ _  ___  ___
  | |  | -_||  _|| . || . || | ||   || -_|
  |_|  |___||_|  |__,||___||_  ||_|_||___|
                           |___|

root@localhost:/# apt-get install docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
docker-ce is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up cgroupfs-mount (1.1) ...
Failed to read /proc/cmdline. Ignoring: Permission denied
Mounting cgroupfs hierarchy/usr/bin/cgroupfs-mount: 32: cd: can't cd to /sys/fs/cgroup
invoke-rc.d: initscript cgroupfs-mount, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package cgroupfs-mount (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up docker-ce (17.09.1~ce-0~debian) ...
Failed to read /proc/cmdline. Ignoring: Permission denied
/etc/init.d/docker: 73: cd: can't cd to /sys/fs/cgroup
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cgroupfs-mount
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@localhost:/#
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker isolates containers using cgroups and namespaces. The installer failed to find `/sys/fs/cgroup`. Either this is not present inside your Debian chroot environment, or, your kernel is too old for cgroup support (pretty likely on Android).

- Does the `/sys/` directory exist for you?
- What kernel are you running? (`uname -a`). Docker requires 3.10 or later.